# What data modelling tool is sufficient for a student learning database design?

Tags: database-design, tools

Disclaimer: I do not intend this to be a question based on opinion and start data wars (I don't know if such things exist in this realm unlike software development and programming languages)

What I want: I want a piece of software (hopefully free, I am a student) that does not necessarily have to come with all the bells and whistles of professional data suites, but one that will allow me to:

- create ERDs
- design my databases, tables, fields,
- create primary keys, link foreign keys
- visualize relations b/w tables

Most of what I have found such as erwin Data Modeler have free trials only. Once again, its not about the bells and whistles since I am what you could call a beginner.

I have a personal desktop app I am working on and I don't want to keep looking at the code to remember the tables nor keep opening SQLITE DB Browser.

Any sense of direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Google for 'Free online data modeler'. https://www.guru99.com/data-modeling-tools-design-database.html

Comment: @McNets why online?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I've get used to use online tools lately. Of course, OP can choose to search for 'free apps'.